# Install python packages with requirements.txt

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When I install packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt` after creating a virtual environment, they get installed but then when I run my python scripts, I still get the `ModuleNotFoundError`

I have also tried `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib` but I still get the error.

Is there anything more required to install those packages. I will appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance.

**UPDATE**

*requirements.txt*

```
pandas
numpy
scikit-learn
flask
flask_restful
scipy
sqlalchemy
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Basically, all modules give me an error. I have to download them separately one by one to get the script working.

Comment: What's content of `requirements.txt` and for what `module` are you getting error ?

Comment: Hey @triandicAnt, I have updated the question. I hope this helps

Comment: Have you activated your virtualenvironment?

Comment: yes i have @shuttle87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me :

Create a virtual environment:

```
virtualenv test
```

Activate your virtual environment:

```
source test/bin/activate
```

Create a module `test` and put `requirements.txt` in that:

```
cd test && sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Create a python script `test.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import flask as fs

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns = ['A', 'B'])
print(df)
```

Run script:

```
(test) test user$ python test.py
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
```

Comment: Would it be different if I create the virtual environment using `conda create -n test python=3.6` because that's how I am doing it right now and a few times before? I always had this issue.

Comment: I haven't used `conda` but if you want to create `virtual environment ` in `python3`, you can use `virtualenv -p python3 virtual_env_name`

Comment: Your example worked. I'll try to figure out what is causing an error in my case. Thanks a lot.